# jsp include function in html5?

Tags: java, html, jsp

Is there a function in html5 that acts like a jsp include?

Something like which can be added automatically to a page by using a single source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if you need such behavior use a server-side language such as PHP. If you cannot do this, you have to use JavaScript to "include" another page by fetching it via AJAX and then adding it to the DOM.

**PHP example:**

```
<?php include 'header.html'; ?>
<h1>hi</h1>
<p>blah blah</p>
<?php include 'footer.html'; ?>
```

**JS example [using jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/load/):**

```
<!doctype html>
<body>
    static stuff
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script>
        $('#content').load('content.html');
    </script>
</body>
```

Do **not** use the JS solution like this. It will make the page unusable by anyone who does not have a JS-capable browser - search engines for example.

Comment: well that's the answer that I am looking for. thanks bro, thanks for the additional details man. yeah, the second example looks dirty. script tags appear where they're not supposed to. appreciate the help! :D

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like an `iframe`?

Comment: hi, not really. just a simple adding of content dynamically from a single source. i'm not really sure what an iframe is, sorry